# How can we redirect Admin Catalog Search to use Elasticsearch?

Tags: admin, catalogsearch, admin-panel, performance, elasticsearch

We have over 2M products in our catalog and growing.  This has made the Admin Catalog Search completely non-functional (it spins until it times out).  How can we update this to also use elasticsearch?  OR is there another way to fix this performance issue?

Comment: have you read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html ?